# pycharm can't complete remote interpreter setup for Docker

Tags: python, docker, pycharm

I'm new to Docker. I'm using Docker & docker-compose, going through a flask tutorial. The base docker image is python 2.7 slim. 
It's running on Linux. docker 1.11.2
The application is working fine. 
I want to get pycharm pro connecting to the remote interpreter, something I have never done before.

I followed the instructions for docker-compose. Initially it was failing because it could not connect to port 2376. I added this port to docker-compose.yml and the error went away. 
However, trying to save the configuration now stalls/hangs with a dialog 'Getting Remote Interpreter Version'. This never completes. Also, I can't quit pycharm. This happens in Pycharm 2016.2 and 2016.3 EAP (2nd).

The help say "SFTP support is required for copying helpers to the server". 
Does this mean I need to do something?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I'm not using docker-machine
The problem was that TCP access to the docker API is not established by default under ubuntu 16.04.

There are suggestions to enable TCP/IP access.

However, JetBrains gave me the simplest solution:

> If you are using Linux it is most likely that Docker installed with
>   its default setup and Docker is expecting to be used through UNIX
>   domain file socket /var/run/docker.sock. And you should specify
>   unix:///var/run/docker.sock in the API URL field. Please comment
>   whether it helps!

This suggestion worked with my Ubuntu 16.04 -derived distribution.

This goes into the Docker entry in PyCharm preferences under Build, Execution, Deployment.

You can also edit this while setting up a remote interpreter, but only by making a new Docker entry.

**TCP/IP Method**

This method works if you want TCP/IP access, but this is a security risk. The socket approach is better, which is probably why it is the default.

https://coreos.com/os/docs/latest/customizing-docker.html

> Customizing docker
>
> The Docker systemd unit can be customized by overriding the unit that
>   ships with the default CoreOS settings. Common use-cases for doing
>   this are covered below.
>
> Enable the remote API on a new socket
>
> Create a file called /etc/systemd/system/docker-tcp.socket to make
>   Docker available on a TCP socket on port 2375.
>
> ```
> [Unit]
> Description=Docker Socket for the API
>
> [Socket]
> ListenStream=2375
> BindIPv6Only=both
> Service=docker.service
>
> [Install]
> WantedBy=sockets.target
> ```
>
> Then enable this new socket:
>
> ```
> systemctl enable docker-tcp.socket
> systemctl stop docker
> systemctl start docker-tcp.socket
> systemctl start docker
> ```
>
> Test that it’s working:
>
> ```
> docker -H tcp://127.0.0.1:2375 ps
> ```

Once I thought to search for ubuntu 16.04 I came across simpler solutions, but I did not test them.

For instance:

https://www.ivankrizsan.se/2016/05/18/enabling-docker-remote-api-on-ubuntu-16-04/

> Edit the file /lib/systemd/system/docker.service
>
> Modify the line that starts with ExecStart to look like this:
>
> ```
> ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker daemon -H fd:// -H tcp://0.0.0.0:2375
> ```
>
> Where my addition is the “-H tcp://0.0.0.0:2375” part. Save the
>   modified file. Restart the Docker service:
>
> ```
> sudo service docker restart
> ```
>
> Test that the Docker API is indeed accessible:
>
> ```
> curl http://localhost:2375/version
> ```

Answer (score 3):

**I - docker-compose up**

I think PyCharm will run `docker-compose up`, have you try to run this command first in your terminal (from where your `docker-compose.yml` is) ?

Maybe if some errors occur, you will get more info in your terminal.

**II - pycharm docker configuration**

Otherwise it could be due to your docker machine configuration in PyCharm.

What I do to configure my machine and to be sure this one is correctly configured:

1 - run `docker-machine ls` in your shell

[image]

2 - copy paste the url without `tcp://`

3 - go to pycharm preferences -> `Build, Execution, Deployement` -> `Docker` -> `+` to create a new server, fill the server `name` field

[image]

4 - paste previously copied url keeping `https://`

5 - fill the path of your machine certificates folder

6 - tick `Import credentials from Docker Machine`

7 - click `Detect` -> your machine should appear in the selection list

8 - save this server

9 - select this server when configuring your remote interpreter, from PyCharm Preferences -> `Project` -> `Project Interpreter` -> `wheel` -> `add remote` -> `Docker` or `Docker Compose`

[image]

10 - you should be able to select a service name

11 - save your new interpreter

11 - try run your test twice, sometimes it could take time to initialize