# docker-compose integration not working in pycharm

Tags: python, docker, pycharm, docker-compose

I've set up docker-compose as a remote interpreter in pycharm using the instructions found [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/using-docker-compose-as-a-remote-interpreter-1.html).

The docker-compose build works fine, but when trying to run a test using this interpreter I get the following error:

```
Testing started at 12:13 AM ...
docker-compose://[/home/melchoir55/gitrepos/python_rest/docker-compose.yml]:python_rest/python -u /opt/.pycharm_helpers/pycharm/_jb_unittest_runner.py --path /opt/project/tests
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bin/docker-compose", line 6, in <module>
  File "compose/cli/main.py", line 71, in main
  File "compose/cli/main.py", line 124, in perform_command
  File "compose/cli/command.py", line 38, in project_from_options
  File "compose/cli/docker_client.py", line 84, in tls_config_from_options
  File "site-packages/docker/tls.py", line 81, in __init__
docker.errors.TLSParameterError: Path to a certificate and key files must be provided through the client_config param. TLS configurations should map the Docker CLI client configurations. See https://docs.docker.com/engine/articles/https/ for API details.
[8964] Failed to execute script docker-compose

Process finished with exit code 255
```

I haven't done much to the system other than installing pycharm, docker, docker-compose, and adding my user to the docker group for permissions. Does anyone know what docker-compose is complaining about here via pycharm?

I did note that there seem to be some env vars which I don't have set related to these certificates, but it isn't clear to me what they should be set to, if I were to set them.

**Update:**

For reference I am running pycharm in Ubuntu within a virtualbox machine.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Turns out using the `TCP socket` API URL was the way to go. I passed the unix socket to the TCP socket, and it worked.

This is the string i use in the Engine API URL `unix:///var/run/docker.sock`.

Found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39941116/pycharm-cant-complete-remote-interpreter-setup-for-docker).

Comment: Once I worked out that "radial" was a spell-corrected "API URL", I put the unix socket name in there and PyCharm could connect.  FWIW, I am using a mac.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds similar to [PY-29205](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-29205) and [PY-29228](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-29228).

Check if certificates folder is correct:

[image]

Comment: My version has an additional option call 'unix socket' which I am using. It has no certificate folder.